# Is it wrong to dynamically add "data-val" and "data-val-required" in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a ViewModel that I can decorate with the `[Required]` attribute (see below). I've come to the point where I need to let the client control which fields are required or not. They can configure this trough XML and all this info is stored in the Model when it's first created. Now I have fields that are not decorated with `[Required]` but still need to get validated (as per "user settings") before submitting (for example the `Phone` field).

```
public class MyBusinessObjectViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; } //compulsory

    public string Phone { get; set; } //not (yet) compulsory, but might become
}
```

If the user will not enter the `Phone` number, the data will still get posted. Wanting not to mess with custom validators, I just add the "data-val" and "data-val-required" attributes to the Html, like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("data-val", "true");
dict.Add("data-val-required", "This field is required.");
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, dict);
```

This forces the client side validation for all the properties that are dynamically set as required. Is this good practice? What kind of side effects can I expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into extending the meta model framework with your own [metadata provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to do the actual binding between your site's configuration and the model metadata. You can actually set the [required property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.isrequired%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) flag to true on the property model metadata during the metadata creation process. I can't remember for sure whether this causes the built in editor templates to generate the attribute, but I think it does. Worst case scenario you can actually create and attach a new `RequiredAttribute` to the property, which is a tad bit kluggy, but works pretty well in certain scenarios.

You could also do this with [IMetadataAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imetadataaware%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) attributes, especially if `Required` is the only metadata aspect your users can customize, but the implementation really depends on what you're trying to do.

One major advantage of using a custom ModelMetadataProvider in your specific case is that you can use dependency injection (via [ModelMetadataProviders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataproviders.current%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) to get your customer settings persistence mechanism into scope, whereas with the data attribute you only get to write an isolated method that runs immediately after the metadata model is created.

Here is a sample implementation of a custom model metadata provider, you'd just have to change the client settings to whatever you wanted to use.

**UPDATED** but not tested at all

```
public class ClientSettingsProvider
{
    public ClientSettingsProvider(/* db info */) { /* init */ }

    public bool IsPropertyRequired(string propertyIdentifier)
    {
       // check the property identifier here and return status
    }

}

public ClientRequiredAttribute : Attribute
{
    string _identifier;
    public string Identifier { get { return _identifer; } }
    public ClientRequiredAttribute(string identifier)
    { _identifier = identifier; }
}

public class RequiredModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    ClientSettings _clientSettings;

    public RequiredModelMetadataProvider(ClientSettings clientSettings)
    {
        _clientSettings = clientSettings;
    }

    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        // alternatively here is where you could 'inject' a RequiredAttribute into the attributes list

        var clientRequiredAttribute = attributes.OfType<ClientRequiredAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        if(clientRequiredAttribute != null && _clientSettings.IsPropertyRequired(clientRequiredAttribute.Identifier))
        {
            // By injecting the Required attribute here it will seem to 
            // the base provider we are extending as if the property was
            // marked with [Required]. Your data validation attributes should
            // be added, provide you are using the default editor templates in
            // you view.
            attributes = attributes.Union(new [] { new RequiredAttribute() });
        }

        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        // REMOVED, this is another way but I'm not 100% sure it will add your attributes
        // Use whatever attributes you need here as parameters...
        //if (_clientSettings.IsPropertyRequired(containerType, propertyName))
        //{
        //    metadata.IsRequired = true;
        //}

        return metadata;
    }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
public class MyModel
{
     [ClientRequired("CompanyName")]
     public string Company { get; set; }
}

public class MyOtherModel
{
     [ClientRequired("CompanyName")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Both of these models would validate the string "CompanyName" against your client settings provider.

Comment: Hy Paul, thanks for your answer. I've spent the last 2 days "playing" around with metadata and dynamically adding attributes to my ViewModels, so this is not really my first choice for solving my problem. It does seem to produce a viable result, but at a time costly expense. I will read into it.

Comment: See edits, it should take about the same amount of code as adding the parameters directly.

Comment: Currently testing. Thanks for the suggestion. I will get back on Monday.

Comment: In my example above for the sake of simplicity I'm just checking EVERY property, but a better approach would be to define a custom attribute like `CustomRequiredAttribute("PropertyIdentifier")` and check to see if the identifier matches. That would make your client settings logic easier, more implementation independent, and ensure that 'bad data' wouldn't be able to make arbitrary properties required. You could also reuse the identifier so that a property shown on multiple model classes would work consistently.

Comment: There's already a custom metadata provider in the code, from one of my team mates. Maybe I can piggyback.

Comment: I got a chance of testing your proposed solution and it could provide an alternative to my solution. I'm still trying to fit a `ClientSettings` into it. It's a bit difficult as I need to negotiate legacy code. Could you please add some side effects of the method I describe in my question? I want to accept your answer.

Comment: See update. Since you said you already have a metadata provider (if it is being used) you'd replace the DataAnnotations provider with yours. This all presumes that the provider in your legacy code in turn is extending the data annotations provider.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was successful in modifying the metadata, as per your suggestion. The problem I was referring to is related to the instantiation of the `CusotmMetadataProvider`. I need to see how can I integrate our current settings and objects, as it needs to be flexible and I must be able to modify the settings at run time (some settings need to be overwritten in Controllers).

Comment: Ah, so one application serves multiple customers I'm guessing? Well you'll probably need something like a ClientSettingsProviderFactory in that case. To provide the actual parameters you'll inject them in the app startup, i.e. add `ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new RequiredModelMetadataProvider(clientSettingsProviderFactory);` to the `Application_Start()` method using whatever IoC you're using to get clientSettingsFactory instance.

Comment: Spot on! That's exactly what I tried. I didn't however liked the flexibility it provided (to many conditions to switch on, no "easy lazy loading") so I decided to piggyback another object. It seems I'm currently hijacking everything. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Not wanting to mess with custom validators, so you messed in the View obfuscating the logic of your validation by removing it from the place where it is expected to be found.

Really, don't be afraid of creating a custom attribute validator. What you are doing right now is getting a technical debt.

Comment: I did have doubts about it, that's why I shared my problem. Say I would take a metadata approach, how can I ensure that the values are set at run time and not during compilation?